# FFT Scipy Calculating Frequency

Tags: python, scipy, fft

I am trying to calculate a signal-frequency by using scipy FFT. By calculating the frequency "by hand" its obviously around 2.5 Hz.

So this is my input signal:
[Signal Amplitude over Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19JeU.png)

this is the code i am using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import fft

##---Get Data
AccZ = np.loadtxt('...', delimiter=';', usecols=(0,3))
Time = np.array(AccZ[:,0])
AccZ = np.array(AccZ[:,1])
Time_Step = Time[1]-Time[0]

##---FFT
AccZ_fft = fft.fft(AccZ) 
Amp = np.abs(AccZ_fft) 

Sample_Freq = fft.fftfreq(AccZ.size, d=Time_Step) 

Amp_Freq = np.array([Amp, Sample_Freq]) 
Amp_Pos = Amp_Freq[0,:].argmax() 
Peak_Freq = Amp_Freq[1, Amp_Pos]
```

This is what i get from the FFT:
[Amplitude over Frequency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4sAQ.png)

Unfortunatly my highest value is always in array position [0] which means my peak frequency from my Sample_Freq array is always 0.

What am i doing wrong here? Would apreciate any help.

Comment: could you add some sample data, such that the error can be recreated?

Comment: you can get the dataset here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AzoXvFl6Ir7KEzPie2xIXk01l0j4j_vn/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

The zeroth bin is always the DC component, i.e. vertical offset of the input function. If you're not interested in this value, you can simply do:

```py
AccZ_fft[0] = 0
```

This is equivalent to doing this to the input:

```py
AccZ -= np.mean(AccZ)
```

and should simplify the the peak finding.

By the way, for real-valued input signals (as yours seems to be), it is advisable to use `np.fft.rfft` instead of `np.fft.fft`. This way, you won't get this symmetrical output with redundant positive and negative frequencies.

Comment: RFFT makes it indeed more easy for me to get whats going on! Deleting the DC component worked perfectly for me as well. Thanks!